# Read registry subkeys from VBA

Tags: vba, registry

I have the following piece of VB code to get the registry subkey (**NOT** the key or the value of a registry). I just need to list out applications in Microsoft subkey (e.g. Office, Notepad, Keyboard etc.).

It worked in **VB.NET** but I'm trying to apply the same code to **VBA** in Macro, I get a run time error saying `"Object variable or With block variable not set"` on the line of `GetOBject` and `EmumKey`. I though the following code should be compatible for both **VB.NET** and **VBA**. 
Can anyone please explain?

```
Dim temp As Object
'On Error Resume Next
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
temp = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & "." & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

Dim rPath As String
rPath = "Software\Microsoft\IdentityCRL\UserExtendedProperties"

Dim arrSubKeys(5) As Object
temp.EnumKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, rPath, arrSubKeys)

For Each ask In arrSubKeys
    MsgBox(ask.ToString)
Next
```

Comment: VB.NET is *nothing* like VBA. Code written for one will not and should not compile in the other.

Comment: I actually get this code snippet on google, and it was written for VBA. Strangely it compiled and worked fine on VB.NET in visual studio but runs into error in VBA Macro in Excel.

Comment: @CodyGray, sorry, it's just not correct nor helpful to say they are 'nothing' like each other.  I wouldn't like anyone reading your comment to believe that. In fact, they are pretty similar, both use BASIC syntax, hence KMC's code snippet is very easy to make work in either environment with minimal change (as per answer below), which is exactly what KMC asked for help with.  We can complain about optimisation, but that's entirely different.

Comment: I...what? Optimization? Yeah, they are *syntactically* similar, but that is superficial only. Which is an important distinction. Perhaps you are thinking of the similarities between VBA and VB 6? VB.NET is a managed language that runs on top of the .NET Framework. Aside from syntax (and even then, the similarities are superficial only), it literally has *nothing* in common with VBA. Code written for one will not work with the other, which is what is implied in the question. @chalky

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For VBA try it like this

- `temp` is an object and needs to be used with Set
- the `temp.Enum` syntax is `temp.EnumKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, rPath, arrSubKeys` not `temp.EnumKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, rPath, arrSubKeys)`
- `Dim` your variables at the top of your code for neatness :)

This code lists all the folders under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\` to the Immediate window of the VBE

```
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
Sub TestME()
    Dim temp As Object
    Dim strComputer As String
    Dim rPath As String
    Dim arrSubKeys()
    Dim strAsk

    strComputer = "."
    Set temp = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & _
    strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

    rPath = "Software\Microsoft\"
    temp.EnumKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, rPath, arrSubKeys
    For Each strAsk In arrSubKeys
        Debug.Print strAsk
    Next
End Sub
```

[image: example output]

Comment: thanks much! it worked fine. Q1: why assign the dot "." to a variable instead of concatenating it directing to the string? Q2: arrSubKeys and strAsk is not declared as a type (i.e. Object, String) and still usable?

Comment: @KMC glad to have helped. 1) The `StrComputer` variable is commonly used in vbscript to refernce differnt machines on a network, the `.` being the local machine. So I went with the more flexible standard rather than hard-coding the `.` 2) That is because these variables are variant, so they can be left undimsioned.

Comment: having just tested this, it would appear that it's even catering for the 32/64 bit issue in HKLM whereby the actual keys are in software\Wow6432Node\...
top work fella!

Comment: for HKLM use 

Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002