# Create new folder in the same folder where the current file is stored (in sharepoint)

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint, office365

I want to run the below `VBA` to create a new folder **within the folder** where the current file is stored. 
 So far I have done this using the following simple `VBA`:

```
Sub Create_Folder()
MkDir Application.ThisWorkbook.Path & "\New Folder"
End Sub
```

---

Now, my company moved to sharepoint and when I run this `VBA` within a sharepoint folder I get `runtime error 76`. 
I assume this is caused because `ThisWorkbook.Path` can not correctly identify the path anymore. 
 Therefore, I checked how the path looks like:

```
https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/Finance1/Freigegebene Dokumente/Controlling/
```

In order to use this path I adjusted it in the `VBA`:

```
Sub Create_Folder()
WorkbookPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
WorkbookPath = "\\" & Replace(Split(WorkbookPath, "//")(1), "/", "\")
MkDir WorkbookPath & "\New Folder"
End Sub
```

However, I am still getting `runtime error 76` when I try to create the new folder.

---

What is strange to me is that when I check the link in the `windows explorer` it loosk totally different to the link that I get with `Application.ThisWorkbook.Path`.

```
C:\Users\firstname.lastname\company\Controlling - Dokumente
```

---

Do you have any idea how I can solve this issue and create a new folder **in the same folder** where the current file is stored?

Comment: Is this file in a synced folder?

Comment: Not sure but in the explorer it has the status column with the cloud- or check-sign next to it. I assume this means that it is a synced folder.

Comment: Check my answer here on how to get the local path of a sharepoint folder: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65605893/1521579

Comment: This problem (converting a OneDrive web path to the local path of the synced folder) now has a more reliable solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73577057/12287457).